# How can I get Netbeans Go to Type (open type) to work in a Maven nested module project?

Tags: netbeans, maven, module, pom.xml

It seems that with nested modules, each with their own POM, it will only detect source files in the root parent module. How can I get the source in all modules in the POM hierarchy to be detected so I can use Go to Type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229651/is-it-possible-to-view-a-multi-module-maven-project-in-eclipse-as-a-hierarchy). It is not possible. It is necessary to include each module (with the standard Maven directory structure) as a separate project.